# Unit testing a controller that depends on a session variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller that depends on a Session variable.  In order to unit test this controller, I came up with the following solution.  It works but I'm wondering if there is a better/cleaner way.  Thanks

Controller

```
    public JsonResult UpdateStatus(ImageUpdateStatus imageUpdateStatus, SessionStateItemCollection sessionItems = null)
    {
        var data = new object();
        string status = null;

        ImageInfo imageInfo = new ImageInfo();
        IImageInfoServices svcImageInfo = new ImageInfoServicesRepository();
        imageInfo = svcImageInfo.GetImageByImageId(imageUpdateStatus.ImageId);

        IDeviceControlServices svcDevice = new DeviceControlServicesRespository();
        IPVSCommandServices svcPVSCmds = new PVSCommandServicesRespository();

        if (imageUpdateStatus.Task == "prep")
        {
            List<UpdateReasonForm> updateReasonForms;

            if (sessionItems != null)
            {
                updateReasonForms = sessionItems["UpdateReasonForms"] as List<UpdateReasonForm>;
            }
            else
            {
                updateReasonForms = Session["UpdateReasonForms"] as List<UpdateReasonForm>;
            }

            foreach (var item in updateReasonForms)
            {
                if (item.ImageId == imageInfo.ImageId)
                {
                    status = svcPVSCmds.PrepImage(imageInfo, item.NewVersion);
                }
            }

            data = new
            {
                status
            };
        }

        if (imageUpdateStatus.Task == "boot")
        {
            status = svcDevice.Boot(imageInfo.ImageId);

            data = new
            {
                status
            };
        }

        return this.Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Unit Test

```
        [TestMethod()]
    public void UpdateStatusTest()
    {
        BuildController target = new BuildController(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        ImageUpdateStatus imageUpdateStatus = new ImageUpdateStatus(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        imageUpdateStatus.ImageId = 3;
        imageUpdateStatus.Task = "prep";
        UpdateReasonForm updateReasonForm = new UpdateReasonForm();
        updateReasonForm.ImageId = 3;
        updateReasonForm.NewVersion = "TestThis";

        List<UpdateReasonForm> updateReasonForms = new List<UpdateReasonForm>();
        updateReasonForms.Add(updateReasonForm);

        var sessionItems = new SessionStateItemCollection();
        sessionItems["UpdateReasonForms"] = updateReasonForms;

        JsonResult actual;
        actual = target.UpdateStatus(imageUpdateStatus, sessionItems);
    }
```

Comment: Use mvcContrib test helpers for MVC. Will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a dependency on Session. You could move your code into a testable method where you inject the dependency at the method level. It looks like you are on this path I would just abstract the code into its own method allowing you to test the functionality regardless of the whether the data comes from session or not.

```
 public JsonResult UpdateStatusDependencyInjection(ImageUpdateStatus imageUpdateStatus, Dictionary<string, object> sessionValues)
        {
        var data = new object();
        string status = null;

        ImageInfo imageInfo = new ImageInfo();
        IImageInfoServices svcImageInfo = new ImageInfoServicesRepository();
        imageInfo = svcImageInfo.GetImageByImageId(imageUpdateStatus.ImageId);

        IDeviceControlServices svcDevice = new DeviceControlServicesRespository();
        IPVSCommandServices svcPVSCmds = new PVSCommandServicesRespository();

        if (imageUpdateStatus.Task == "prep")
        {
            List<UpdateReasonForm> updateReasonForms;

            if (sessionItems != null)
            {
                updateReasonForms = sessionItems["UpdateReasonForms"] as List<UpdateReasonForm>;
            }
            else
            {
                updateReasonForms = Session["UpdateReasonForms"] as List<UpdateReasonForm>;
            }

            foreach (var item in updateReasonForms)
            {
                if (item.ImageId == imageInfo.ImageId)
                {
                    status = svcPVSCmds.PrepImage(imageInfo, item.NewVersion);
                }
            }

            data = new
            {
                status
            };
        }

        if (imageUpdateStatus.Task == "boot")
        {
            status = svcDevice.Boot(imageInfo.ImageId);

            data = new
            {
                status
            };
        }

        return this.Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing in the session values as a parameter you can mock the session state like here:

[How do you mock the session object collection using Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524457/how-do-you-mock-the-session-object-collection-using-moq)

Comment: Your answer should contain the information contained in that article in case the article link goes bad.

Answer (score 0):

http://codingsmith.co.za/a-better-way-of-working-with-httpcontext-session-in-mvc/

This is my implementation of an interface wrapper for Session.
Its currently in production and works fine, its injected into my controllers, but I can use one of the other implementations manually when testing